# How to use sed command for search and replace special string?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm working on the bootstrap script for setup the server on VM. So, I can't run sed command for replace string in the file.

In setup.rb file:

```
token = ENV['SERVER_URL]
```

So I want to replace ENV['SERVER_URL'] with my domain is https://my.domain.com

```
sed -i -e 's/ENV\\[\'SERVER_URL\'\\]/https\:\\//my.domain.com/g setup.rb
```

So it don't work. Please help me to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use outer double quotes instead, to avoid having to deal with the single quotes in the substitution argument.

`sed -i -e "s/ENV\['SERVER_URL'\]/my.domain.com/g" setup.rb`

Comment: `sed -i '1axxx' setup.rb `where xxx is the text u want to add

Comment: I got error: sed: 1: "setup.rb": unterminated substitute pattern

Comment: Sounds like you are on BSD/OSX. Try `sed -i '' '1axxx' seup.rb` where still xxx needs to be replaced with what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e "s#ENV\['SERVER_URL\]#https://my.domain.com#" setup.rb
```

- use double quote for because there is a single quote in search pattern
- use other separator (here `#`) in `s///` action because `/` is in replacment pattern
- be carefful on domain that no meta character are used like `&` (simple domain have no risk, full URL well) that have special meaning in replacement pattern